# How can I use react router with a path of more than on / (no params)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to use react router using a composed path (ex: /demo/common). Common is not a param.
I would like to have something like this:

```
    <Route
       exact
       path="/demo/page1"
       component={Page1}
    />

    <Route
       exact
       path="/demo/page2"
       component={Page2}
    />
```

But when I try to access any of those routes it will just show me a white screen.

Thanks.

Comment: Are the Page1 and Page2 components alright?

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes, they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a parent route with `path="/demo"` and a parent component called `ParentPage`:

```
<Route path="/demo" component={ParentPage} />
```

Please note that **parent route must not have `exact` prop**, in order to do a nesting behavior.

2. Under `ParentPage`, you will have `Page1` and `Page2` as children:

```
<ParentPage>
 <Route
   path="/demo/page1"
   component={Page1}
 />
 <Route
   path="/demo/page2"
   component={Page2}
 />
</ParentPage>
```

It doesn't matter if the child component has `exact` prop or not.